# android studio does not recognize libraries

Tags: android

jumped electricity while I was working with Android Studio..
After I opened the new Android Studio and began the problems!

[image: screenshot]

The error would be written in red, have not been able to solve this problem
I tried to uninstall and then reinstall, including JDK and SDK, but nothing to do!

It seems that they are not recognized the packages and library of Java..
Does anyone have any idea what has happened?

Comment: Show your build.gradle file content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be that your project doesn't contain any android SDK setting. 
Check this `File > Project Structure > Project SDK` should be a some of android sdk's.
So as `File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies` tab

Comment: Now the only problem I have, is that it does not import the ActionBarActivity

Comment: You need to add a support library v4 and v7

Answer (score 29):

I recently had this problem and solved it by closing the project and doing 'Import project'.

Comment: I had this problem, building was fine, just the editors flagging some imports as errors. Deleted the .idea and iml files did new import of the project and all was fine.

Comment: @Rene dude, thanks, I was thinking about a suicide because this issues bugged me a lot, but now it is resolved. I deleted .idea folder and imported the project and Thats IT. it works perfectly

Comment: Still running into this issue. Deleting the .idea folder solved it.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue since Android Studio 3.x versions. This answer worked perfectly for me. didn't even need to delete any `.iml` file or `.idea` folder.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue.
Try This: `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't work, at least for my 2 projects, I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, building was successful, just the editors flagging some of my imports as errors. I closed the project, deleted the .idea and .iml files then did new import of the project and it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files` worked for me.